# jquery - format yymmdd_hhmmss validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an text input and i require the user to only be allowed to enter numbers like this "`150301_123456"` basically the `yymmdd_hhmmss` format,

How can i do this in JQuery to auto validate it?

i tried to use jquery Date Picker and jQuery number Mask plugins but they don't provide what i need here.

i am currently doing it like this:

```
    $('#aq_utcstart_' + idc).on("keyup", function(val)
    {
        var value = $(this).val();
        var segments = value.split("_");

        if (segments.length <= 1)
        {
            $(this).addClass("inputfatal");                 
            return false;
        }

        if (value.indexOf("_") < 0 || (segments[0].length < 6 || segments[1].length < 4) || 
        (segments[0].length > 6 || segments[1].length > 6))
        {                   
            $(this).addClass("inputfatal");
        }
        else
        {                   
            $(this).removeClass("inputfatal");
        }
    });
```

but i would like to do it better, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jquery validator with regular expression on the element that you want. Example of use:

```
$.validator.addMethod("rulexample",
function(value, element){
return /*regular expression*/.test(value);},
"Message in case the format doesn't fit what you want");

$('#myElement').validate({
rules: {nameofmyelement:{rulexample:true}}
});
```

Hope this will help!

Comment: i couldnt make this work, but thanks for the suggestion, I have updated my post with what i am using to get by but it's obliviously not a good approach.